# Magento 2 How to get recently view product collection

Tags: magento-2.1.7, magento2.2-dev

My requirement is to get recently view product collection.

Below function is used in Magento1 :

```
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')->getItemsCollection();
```

I want to use above collection in magento2.

Comment: Hi @shyam did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace [Vendor]\RecentlyViewed\Block\Customer;

use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed;
use \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Factory as IndexFactory;

class RecentlyViewed extends Viewed
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Factory $indexFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        Context $context,
        Visibility $productVisibility,
        IndexFactory $indexFactory,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $productVisibility, $indexFactory, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }


    /**
     * @return \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Index\Collection\AbstractCollection
     */
    public function getRecentlyViewedProducts()
    {
        $collection = $this->getItemsCollection();
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Comment: its not working i tried

Comment: I need recently viewed products array in Magento2

Comment: please try widgate

Comment: if any problems with thi code..give me updat.

Comment: @Divyesh Does this work for in Magento > 2.2 ? It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't for me. See this [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3890)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code. It is useful for current user recent view product display :

```
protected $recentlyViewed;

public function __construct(
...
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed
) {
...
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
}

public function getMostRecentlyViewed(){
    return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();
    // return recently viewed products for the customer
}
```

Comment: Hi @rohan can we fetch collection by customer id?

Comment: Yes. You can refer this answer => https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251228/51810

Comment: thanks for reply but where we need to add customer id for filtering?

Comment: It will automatically return collection as you logging user or guest.

Comment: with the above logic can we implement REST API? please advise