# Get recently viewed products programmatically in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: product, magento2.2, programmatically, recently-viewed

I am trying to fetch recently viewed products.

I tried to implement the provided code from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194346/magento-2-how-to-get-recently-view-product-collection) but did not get any success.

Comment: have u found a solution yet ?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code in your template file for get recently viewed products in any place,

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")
            ->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")
            ->setProductsCount("6")
            ->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml")
            ->toHtml(); 
 ?>
```

You can change `setProductsCount()` as you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Nikunj Vadariya but it is not working. It is not displaying anything. Can I get recently viewed product collection programmatically?

Comment: do you want to display in product detail page?

Comment: No, I want to display at multiple places. Basically, I want recently viewed products collection.

Comment: not working in magento  2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

With this custom code, you can also get a most viewed products

```
  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $reportCollectionFactory,   
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager   

    ){
        $this->reportCollectionFactory = $reportCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


public function getMostViewedProducts()
{
      $storeId =  $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

      $collection = $this->reportCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addViewsCount()->setStoreId(
                    $storeId
            )->addStoreFilter(
                    $storeId
            );
      $items = $collection->getItems();
      return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Yogesh. Your code works fine but I need recently viewed products.

Comment: ohh.. sorry for misunderstanding...!

Answer (score 0):

You can get recently view product by below code

```
protected $recentlyViewed;

public function __construct(
...
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed
) {
...
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
}

/**
 * Get recently viewed products for the customer
 *
 */
public function getMostRecentlyViewed(){
    return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Suresh Chikani but it is not returning anything.

Comment: It will be get collection after view any product.

Comment: I tried that also but still it returns nothing.

Comment: in which page do you showing products?

Comment: On category page.

Comment: Are you login or not?

Comment: Yes I am logged in.

Comment: @SureshChikani how to filter this collection by customer id?  please advise

Comment: not working in magento 2.3.5

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari, did you get solution for 2.3.5?