# Magento 2 how to add a widget Recently viewed products

Tags: magento2, product, products, ratings, recently-viewed

If you have add product review and rating and approved admin side. After you have seen on recently view product.

Comment: which page ????

Comment: @RkRathod homepage

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226162/get-recently-viewed-products-programmatically-in-magento-2-2-2

Comment: @RkRathod in no example, dependencies for the code to work, as well as where to enter it

Comment: you want to disaply recent view product programatically on home page Right??

Comment: @RkRathod, yes, I need to add a rating to this widget and for this you need to add it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Add `cms_index_index.xml` in `vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

**then add the following code to the xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                     
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="vendor_module::home_page.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Create `home_page.phtml` on vendor/module/view/frontend/templates/home_page.phtml

**then add the following code to the phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")
            ->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")
            ->setProductsCount("6")
            ->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml")
            ->toHtml(); 
 ?>
```

Comment: but it can be done via cms block, but programmatically? my patches render the page in blocks so that the client could swap the page

Comment: this code for programatically add widget on home page.