# magento2 recently viewed products collection is not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, recently-viewed

I need magento2 recently viewed product collection I tried below code but not working

```
$_recentlyViewedProductCollection = $this->reportProductViewed->getItemsCollection();
        $_recentlyViewedProductCollection->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
                                         ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount()) // load 10 products
                                         ->load();
```

can anyone please help me.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251228 try this answer.

Comment: I tried that two methods but not working

Comment: Did you refreshed data from admin?

Comment: yes refreshed the admin reports also still same issue.