# Magento 2: how Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed worked?

Tags: magento2

how `Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed` worked,
how get recently view products by customer id?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251228/85907

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the collection of recently viewed product for current customer then this is the method

```
protected $recentlyViewed;

public function __construct(
...
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed
) {
...
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
}

/**
 * Get recently viewed products for the customer
 *
 */
public function getMostRecentlyViewed(){
    return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();
}
```

**EDIT**

This code is for logged-in customer so you need customerID you can get customer id from customer session

Comment: how i get by customer_id

Comment: @YoanesRicard  please check i edit the answer

Comment: @TirthPatel so if i have customer ID how to insert customer ID in your code

Comment: thanks @TirthPatel for updating my ans i thought he would be aware that he can retrieve customer id from customer session thats why i have not mentioned it. glad you did. thanks again